# I like the series Lord of the Rings

Tags: grammar, usage

Instead of **"I like the Lord of the Rings series"**, can I say **"I like the series Lord of the Rings"**? Are they interchangeable structures? Another example sentence: **"Do you like the series Lord of the Rings?"** Can I say this instead of **"Do you like the Lord of the Rings series?"**?

Answer (score 2):

With TV and movie titles you will hear it both ways, though it's a little awkward to put the title before the noun when the title begins with *The*:

> Did you like *The Lord of the Rings* trilogy?
>
> Did you like the trilogy, *The Lord of the Rings*?
>
> Did you like the series, *The Detectorists*?
>
> Did you like *The Detectorists* series?

To my ear, when native speakers (and I am one) put the title in front of the noun, and the title begins with *The*, the word *The* is spoken as if it were not a part of the title.

Comment: I may be a little different I would always take a small pause to emphasise that The was part of the title.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you. I haven't thought about it. Would it be wrong to say **"Do you like the the Lord of the Rings series"**? I guess so.

Comment: @DereMemo: You will not hear native speakers saying "the *The*..."